# Is there any way to get firebaesevisionimagelabel data in oncreate?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

Im trying to make copy of firebasevisionimagelabel, but only it works in function after then i can't get any of label in oncreate

This is firebase,written in kotlin. i've put string in wordpilec but i can't load it in oncreate

```
private fun runDetector (bitmap : Bitmap?){

        val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap!!)
        val options = FirebaseVisionCloudImageLabelerOptions.Builder()
            .setConfidenceThreshold(0.7f)
            .build()
        val labeler = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getCloudImageLabeler(options)
        labeler.processImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { labels -> processResultfromcloud(labels)

            } 
private fun processResultfromcloud(labels: List<FirebaseVisionImageLabel>) {

        for (label in labels) {
            builder.append(label.text).append(",")

        }
       wordpilec = builder.toString()
        stringtoArray(wordpilec)


    }
```

I expect strings should be same but one is null the other is perfect . I can not get perfect one

Answer (score 0):

The detector runs asynchronously, and I'm guessing you are trying to access wordpilec in onCreate before the detector has assigned a value assigned to it. You could try and move the operation you are trying to do with the string to the success listener instead.